# Trying to create a Bash function

Tags: bash, function

What is wrong with this? I can't seem to assign anything to the $SITE var. The "rm"s don't work either. Am I concatenation the command and var wrong?

```
newsite () {
    local SITE = $1;
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then # Is parameter #1 zero length?
            echo 'Please give the site a name'
            read = SITENAME;
            $SITE = $SITENAME
    fi

    git clone git://mydomain/site_template.git $SITE
    echo "New site has been created called: \"$SITE\"."
    rm -rf $SITE"/.git";
    rm $SITE"/README.txt";
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take care of whitespaces:

```
local SITE=$1
```

also:

```
read SITENAME
```

and

```
SITE=$SITENAME
```

Comment: Thanks yi_H. My problem was that "$SITE = $SITENAME;" in not correct. I needed to remove the "$" from "$SITES"

Comment: @Pardoner, you also cannot have spaces around the `=` -- this is fundamental to sh syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
function newsite {    
   SITE=$1;
   if [ -z "$1" ]
   then
            echo 'Please give the site a name';
            read = SITENAME;
            $SITE = $SITENAME;
    fi

    git clone git://mydomain/site_template.git $SITE
    echo "New site has been created called: \"$SITE\"."
    rm -rf $SITE"/.git";
    rm $SITE"/README.txt";
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Also, how would I check to see if the repo was successfully cloned before I remove anything?